# How to count only the number of directories from a path

Tags: c, file, counting, stat

I am trying to count only the directories from a path, but it doesn't work. So, i don't want to number both files and directories, i want only the directories. Could you help me, please?
The code:

```
int listdir(char *dir) {
    struct dirent *dp;
    struct stat s;
    DIR *fd;
    int count = 0;

    if ((fd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listdir: can't open %s\n", dir);
    }
    while ((dp = readdir(fd)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        stat(dp->d_name, &s);
        if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))
        count++;
    }
    closedir(fd);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: use `S_ISREG()` to tell if a dir entry is a regular file, otherwise it's a directory (or a link).

Comment: It doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your stat() call will fail, since you are not in the correct directory. This you can solve by either changing the current directory, or generate full paths and give to stat as argument.

Some Unixes, you can optimize away the stat call by looking at struct dirent, the d_type field

```
int listdir(char *dir) {
    struct dirent *dp;
    struct stat s;
    DIR *fd;
    int count = 0;

    if ((fd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "listdir: can't open %s\n", dir);
    }
    chdir (dir); /* needed for stat to work */
    while ((dp = readdir(fd)) != NULL) {
        if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
#ifdef _DIRENT_HAVE_D_TYPE
        switch (dp->d_type)
        {
          case DT_UNKNOWN:
            stat(dp->d_name, &s);
            if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)) count++;
            break;
          case DT_DIR:
            count++;
            break;
        }
#else
        stat(dp->d_name, &s);
        if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)) count++;
#endif            
    }
    closedir(fd);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: could you explain a little how to do?

Comment: Stian, how can i use chdir on windows?

Comment: first hit on google reveals https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235420.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7fwze1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you want...

- written in C
- count the number of directoriesfrom a path.
- the counting function will returns `int` value.

I have no idea about your environment, so it is just a example solution.

If you can use [glob](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), it is so easy to count the number of directories. that is: main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PATH 1023

int countDirectories(char* dir)
{
    char path[MAX_PATH] = "";
    strcat(path, dir);
    strcat(path, "/*");

    glob_t globbuf;
    long i, count = 0;

    if (glob(path, GLOB_NOSORT | GLOB_ONLYDIR, NULL, &globbuf) == 0)
    {
        count = globbuf.gl_pathc;
        for (i = 0; i < globbuf.gl_pathc; i++)
        {
            count += countDirectories(globbuf.gl_pathv[i]);
        }
    }
    globfree(&globbuf);

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int count;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        count = countDirectories(argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        count = countDirectories(".");
    }

    printf("there are %d directories.\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

and you can try this like:

```
> gcc main.c -o testglob
> ./testglob /path/to/target/dir
```

then you'll receive output like this:

```
path = /path/to/target/dir/*, there are N directories
```

thanks.

Comment: edited:) you can use my `countDirectories` as your `listdir` function. `glob` is the function searches files/directories by _pattern_. and using flag `GLOB_ONLYDIR`, we can search only the directory. as a result of this, you can find the number of directories in the `path`.